# What is the difference between concatMap and flatMap in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, flatmap, concatmap

It seems that these 2 functions are pretty similar. They have same signature (accepting `rx.functions.Func1<? super T, ? extends Observable<? extends R>> func`), and their marble diagrams look exactly same. Can't paste the pics here, but here's one for [concatMap](http://netflix.github.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#concatMap%28rx.functions.Func1%29), and here's one for [flatMap](http://netflix.github.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#flatMap%28rx.functions.Func1%29). There seems to be some subtle difference in the description of resulting `Observable`, where one produced by `concatMap` contains items that result from concatinating resulting Observables, and the one produced by `flatMap` contains items that result from first merging the resulting Observables, and emitting the result of that merger.

However, this subtlety is totally unclear to me. Can anyone give a better explanation of this difference, and ideally give some examples illustrating this difference.

Comment: Hey, your links are broken. Could you fix them.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

As you wrote, the two functions are very similar and the subtle difference is how the output is created ( after the mapping function is applied).

Flat map uses [merge operator](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables#merge) while concatMap uses [concat operator](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Mathematical-and-Aggregate-Operators#concat).

As you see the concatMap output sequence is ordered - all of the items emitted by the first Observable being emitted before any of the items emitted by the second Observable,
while flatMap output sequence is merged - the items emitted by the merged Observable may appear in any order, regardless of which source Observable they came from.

Comment: Thanks, this explanation helps. I would add, based on my own research, that one major difference coming from the fact that these two functions operate on `merge` and `concat` operators. In case of `concat`, subscriptions to concatenated observables happen sequentially, only after previous one completes, while in case of `merge` all subscription happen immediately. That can make big difference if the underlying observables are hot.

Comment: This is a complementary explanation with a nice example: http://fernandocejas.com/2015/01/11/rxjava-observable-tranformation-concatmap-vs-flatmap/

Comment: @Marek could you update the link for concat - brings me to a page with no mention of it

Answer (score 54):

Even though the answers here are good it wasn't easy to spot the difference without an example. So, I created a simple example for this:

```
@Test
public void flatMapVsConcatMap() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("******** Using flatMap() *********");
    Observable.range(1, 15)
            .flatMap(item -> Observable.just(item).delay(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            .subscribe(x -> System.out.print(x + " "));

    Thread.sleep(100);

    System.out.println("\n******** Using concatMap() *********");
    Observable.range(1, 15)
            .concatMap(item -> Observable.just(item).delay(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            .subscribe(x -> System.out.print(x + " "));

    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

> ******** Using flatMap() *********
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 8 11 13 15 10 12 14
>
> ******** Using concatMap() *********
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

As it could be seen from the output, the results for `flatMap` are unordered while for `concatMap` they're.

Comment: Very clear example, also that mean that if instead of `Observalbe.range(1,15)`, I have `Observable.of("unique")` then concatMap and flatMap gonna output the same result.

Answer (score 29):

One very important difference: the `concatMap` waits for the current emitted observable to complete and `flatMap` doesn't. `flatMap` tries to start as many possible. Simply said - you cannot concatenate something infinite. **Just make sure that the observables you emit in `concatMap` can complete**, otherwise the whole flow will get stuck waiting for the current observable to complete to concatenate the next one.

Answer (score 17):

I find example in most upvoted answer not much clear, so i post one that helped me to understand difference between flatMap and concatMap.

FlatMap takes emissions from source observable, then create new observable and **merge** it to original chain, while concatMap **concat** it to original chain.

Main difference is that concatMap() will merge
each mapped Observable sequentially and fire it one at a time. It will only move to the
next Observable when the current one calls onComplete().

Here is **flatMap** example:

```
private void flatMapVsConcatMap() throws InterruptedException {
    Observable.just(5, 2, 4, 1)
            .flatMap(
                    second ->
                            Observable.just("Emit delayed with " + second + " second")
                                    .delay(second, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            )
            .subscribe(
                    System.out::println,
                    Throwable::printStackTrace
            );

    Thread.sleep(15_000);
}
```

Will result in :

> Emit delayed with 1 second
>   Emit delayed with 2 second
>   Emit delayed with 4 second
>   Emit delayed with 5 second

Here is **concatMap** example:

```
private void flatMapVsConcatMap() throws InterruptedException {
    Observable.just(5, 2, 4, 1)
            .concatMap(
                    second ->
                            Observable.just("Emit delayed with " + second + " second")
                                    .delay(second, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            )
            .subscribe(
                    System.out::println,
                    Throwable::printStackTrace
            );

    Thread.sleep(15_000);
}
```

Will result in :

> Emit delayed with 5 second
>   Emit delayed with 2 second
>   Emit delayed with 4 second
>   Emit delayed with 1 second

**Note to use Thread.sleep()** because **delay()** operates by default on the computation Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

First of all, flatMap is same as mergeMap in Rxjs. So that is one confusion less.
So there are two observables..

1) o1: A simple list of items from(['Kitty','Donald','Batman'])

2) process_o1(): process_o1() is a function that takes as one parameter 'item' and does something with it and returns an Observable which on completion emits 'done with [item]'.

```
o1.pipe(mergeMap(item => process_o1(item))).subscribe(data => {
console.log(data);
});
```

Here we are going to see:-
done with Kity.

done with Donald.

done with Batman.

without any guarantee that Kitty comes before Donald and Donald comes before Batman.
This is because, as soon as the outer observable emits an item the inner observable is 
subscribed.

===
But in case of concatMap:-

```
o1.pipe(concatMap(item => process_o1(item))).subscribe(data => {
console.log(data);
});
```

We have the guarantee of the below sequence:-

done with Kity.

done with Donald.

done with Batman.

Because, with concatMap operator, the inner Observable is not subscribed before the previous inner Observable returns.

The outer observable is free to just go ahead and emit all its values, but the concatMap will make sure that it deals with each of those values one by one and maintains the order.
Hence the name concatMap.

In crux, if you are keen on maintaining the order of doing things, you should use concatMap.
But if you dont care about order, you can go ahead with mergeMap which will subscribe to all inner Observables at once and keep emitting values as and when they return.

Answer (score 0):

Others already pointed out the answer but in case it is not too evident, there is a risk of creating undesired parallelism with flatMap, if this is undesired you can use concatMap, or the overload `flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Publisher<? extends V>> mapper, int concurrency)`

Answer (score -1):

**flatMap vs concatMap**

`flatMap` - merge - if new item is emitted it has a priority

`concatMap` - concatenate - add into the end - emit full sequence and only after that(previous was finished) is able to emit next sequence

[image]

[[map vs flatMap]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67590499/4770877)