# Convert Observable<List<Car>> to a sequence of Observable<Car> in RxJava

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

Given a list of cars (`List<Car> cars`), I can do:

```
Observable.just(cars); //returns an Observable that emits one List<Car>
Observable.from(cars); //returns an Observable that emits a squence of Car
```

Is there a way I can go from an `Observable` of a `List<Car>` to a sequence of `Observable<Car>`?

Something like a `from` without parameters

```
Obserable.just(cars).from()
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can map an `Observable<List<Car>>` to `Observable<Car>` like so:

```
yourListObservable.flatMapIterable(x -> x)
```

Note that flatMapping might not preserve the order of the source observable. If the order matters to you, use `concatMapIterable`. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571491/what-is-the-difference-between-concatmap-and-flatmap-in-rxjava) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

you can use this

```
flatMap { t -> Observable.fromIterable(t) }
```