# What's the Rx.NET equivalent to flatMapIterable?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

> Today I finally stumbled upon the solution of a really trivial RX problem: Suppose you have an Observable which returns Lists of items. Like `Observable<List<String>>`. You often receive something like this as responses from web APIs.

> However chances are you want to operate on the single items, in this case the Strings.

> `flatMapIterable` to the rescue! This handy operator flattens a stream of `Iterables` into a stream generated from the single items of these `Iterables` by means of a mapping function.

[RxJava: flattening a stream of Iterables | by Sven Bendel](https://medium.com/@ubuntudroid/rxjava-flattening-a-stream-of-iterables-ea26f593ba07)

I'm writing in .NET Core if that matters.

Example in RxJava: [Convert `Observable<List<Car>>` to a sequence of `Observable<Car>` in RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672705/convert-observablelistcar-to-a-sequence-of-observablecar-in-rxjava)

Comment: Fun fact: the operation you want is the bind operation on the observable monad.

Comment: @EricLippert, I was asking for a specific version of bind called flatMapIterable (in RxJava). It appears this is not available in Rx.NET.

Comment: It is available ```listEmittingObservable.SelectMany(item => item)```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LINQ operation to map a collection-of-collection-of-items into an aggregated collection of items is `SelectMany`. This operation exists in System.Reactive as well, allowing you to create a single Observable from a collection of Observables:

http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/08_Transformation.html#SelectMany

```
Observable.Range(1,3)
          .SelectMany(i => Observable.Range(1, i))
          .Dump("SelectMany");
```

> ...we will now get an output with the result of each sequence ([1], [1,2] and [1,2,3]) flattened to produce [1,1,2,1,2,3].

```
SelectMany-->1
SelectMany-->1
SelectMany-->2
SelectMany-->1
SelectMany-->2
SelectMany-->3
SelectMany completed
```

Comment: Thanks! But my question was for a flatMapIterable whereas SelectMany is just flatMap. Check out the article and the SO question I linked to for an explanation. It appears there is no Rx.NET equivalent so I'll just stick with combining SelectMany and .ToObservable.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The question is asking how to convert `IObservable<IList<T>>` to `IObservable<T>`.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me at first until @Shlomo explained. I updated my answer with code matching the flatMapIterable example: ```listEmittingObservable.SelectMany(item => item)```.

Answer (score 0):

It really is trivial to to do this in C#. Just do this:

```
IObservable<IList<int>> source =
    Observable.Return(new [] { 1, 2, 3 }.ToList());

IObservable<int> output =
    from list in source
    from item in list
    select item;
```

Simple.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: My mistake, it's also SelectMany as an overloaded method:

```
public IObservable<string> IterateObservable(IList<string> strings)
{
    return strings
        .ToObservable()
        .Buffer(100) // IObservable<IList<string>>
        .SelectMany(item => item); // IObservable<string>
}
```

It appears there is no equivalent to flatMapInterable in Rx.NET so you must stick with combining SelectMany and ToObservable. Plus more to actually apply a transformation to each item.

Example (same as the RxJava example in the stackoverflow link):

```
public IObservable<string> IterateObservable(IList<string> strings)
{
    return strings
        .ToObservable()
        .Buffer(100)
        .SelectMany(list => list.ToObservable());
}
```

To perform an operation on it similar to flatMapIterable (but more verbose of course):

```
public IObservable<string> IterateObservable(IList<string> strings)
{
    return strings
        .ToObservable()
        .Buffer(100)
        .SelectMany(
                list => list.ToObservable()
                    .Select( stringInList => stringInList.Trim()));
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, the other answer is correct. There are overloads of SelectMany that accept a Func to IEnumerable (the .NET equivalent of Iterable).

Comment: Ohh, it's an overload that makes sense! My mistake